# Energy balance in a thermodynamic system

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, flow

I think I've missed this point in class but I was wondering how to determine for example if I have a turbine, the Energy balance would look something like this:

$W$ as work $h_1$ as intake and $h_2$ as exhaust of the turbine; assuming adiabatic turbine and internal energy is 0 we get: $W+m(h_1-h_2)=0$ or $\frac Wm=(h_1-h_2)$.

after all this my question is:
How do you determine the position of the $h_1$ and $h_2$ of the equation?
I know that for a pump it would be the opposite, meaning $h_2-h_1$ instead of $h_1-h_2$
So say I have a condenser, and a cooler... how would I determine the energy balance equation for those, (assuming steady state system)?

I hope I've been clear enough in my question!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you are trying to do a thermodynamic energy balance hence adiabatic. If that's so, it'll be too complex of an analysis and computation for a full turbine. I'm not sure this site is the best for this.

Comment: Why? Its rather simple... I've given examples. don't focus on the turbine.

Comment: $m$ stand for what?

Comment: $W+m(h_1-h_2)=0$: if $m$ stands for mass then that equation is not dimensionally consistent.

Comment: W=N*m=J
h=J/g or KJ/Kg
therefore, (KJ/KG)*KG=KJ...
and so... I dont see what you mean by not dimensionally consistent...

Comment: This is all based on the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics, which involves possible flows into and out of the control volume.  For steady state operation, what is the equation for this that has been covered in your course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to keep your signs straight. By convention, work done by the system (e.g., turbine work) is considered positive and work done on the system (e.g., pump work) is considered negative. In the case of heat, heat into the system is positive and out is negative. With these conventions, the first law is

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

The enthalpy of steam encompasses both internal energy and the product of pressure and volume.

Fig 1 below show the energy balance for turbines, pumps and compressors. For Turbines $h_{1}>h_{2}$. For pumps and compressors $h_{2}>h_{1}$

Fig 2 shows it for boilers, condensers and evaporators. For boilers and evaporators, $h_{2}>h_{1}$. For condensers $h_{1}>h_{2}$.

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]